# how to Convert PST to GMT(-0800) in java?

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

Actually in my java program like the following code...

```
  String date1=null;
  String formate="IST";
  SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("z");

   SimpleDateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("'GMT('Z')'");
   date1 = gmtFormat.format(sourceFormat.parse(formate));
   System.out.println(date1);//output GMT(+0530)
```

Hear it is giving Correct Value but the timezone may change like `PST---- GMT(-0800)` will so.

But my code alway show only `GMT(+0530)`

Please help me to convert timezone `ACT,,PST,IST.....etc`  to `GMT(+11:00),GMT(-08:00),GMT(+0530).......etc`

Comment: The question is not clear by any means. What do you want to achieve considering the big picture? Please add details, and possibly more code.

Comment: In particular, converting time zones doesn't make any sense. Display a date for a given time zone does make sense.

Comment: Some test input, expected output, and actual output wouldn't go amiss either, and if you really want to treat everyone, put it in a table so it's easy to read!

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("z");

java.text.SimpleDateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("'GMT('ZZZ')' zzzz");

java.util.Date date1 = sourceFormat.parse("IST");

TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");

gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);

//System.out.println("Source date: " + date1);

System.out.println("   "+ gmtFormat.format(date1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Way cleaner in my opinion.

```
        TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");
        long gmtOffset = gmtTime.getOffset(new Date().getTime())/ TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1);
```